# How to test function that we get from action, has been called?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

So I was trying to create a unit test using jest in ReactJS. The Unit test itself just to verify if the function (from action) has been called

I already tried to mock the function, but the result tells that I must mock the function

Here the code of the function that I want to create a unit test

```
import { testfunction } from '../../actions/auth';

handleSubmit(userParams) {
    this.setState({ form: { ...this.state.form, isFetching: true } });
    this.props.dispatch(testfunction(userParams,
      this.successCallback.bind(this), this.errorCallback.bind(this)));
  }
```

and for the unit test

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import Login from '../../../components/auth/Login';

const mockStore = configureStore([thunk]);
const initialState = {
  history: { },
};
const store = mockStore(initialState);
let wrapper;
let history;
let testfunction;
beforeEach(() => {
  testfunction= jest.fn();
  history = { push: jest.fn() };
  wrapper = shallow(
    <Login
      history={history}
      store={store}
      testfunction={testfunction}
    />
  );
});

describe('handleSubmit()', () => {
    test('should call testfunction props', () => {
      const component = wrapper.dive();
      const instance = component.instance();
      const sampleUserParams = {
        email: 'test@test.com',
        password: 'samplePassword123',
      };
      instance.handleSubmit(sampleUserParams);

      expect(testfunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

I just want to check if the "testfunction" is called when I called `handleSubmit` function. But the error message is:

> "Expected mock function to have been called."

it feels my way to mock the function is wrong. Does anyone know how to correct way to test that function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution:

`index.tsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { testfunction } from './testfunction';

class Login extends Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      form: {}
    };
  }

  public render() {
    const userParams = {};
    return (
      <div className="login">
        <form onSubmit={() => this.handleSubmit(userParams)}>some form</form>
      </div>
    );
  }

  private handleSubmit(userParams) {
    this.setState({ form: { ...this.state.form, isFetching: true } });
    this.props.dispatch(testfunction(userParams, this.successCallback.bind(this), this.errorCallback.bind(this)));
  }

  private successCallback() {
    console.log('successCallback');
  }
  private errorCallback() {
    console.log('errorCallback');
  }
}

export { Login };
```

`testFunction.ts`:

```
async function testfunction(userParams, successCallback, errorCallback) {
  return {
    type: 'ACTION_TYPE',
    payload: {}
  };
}
export { testfunction };
```

Unit test:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { Login } from './';
import { testfunction } from './testfunction';

jest.mock('./testfunction.ts');

describe('Login', () => {
  const dispatch = jest.fn();
  const sampleUserParams = {
    email: 'test@test.com',
    password: 'samplePassword123'
  };
  it('handleSubmit', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Login dispatch={dispatch} />);
    expect(wrapper.is('.login')).toBeTruthy();
    expect(wrapper.find('form')).toHaveLength(1);
    wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit');
    const cmpInstance = wrapper.instance();

    expect(dispatch).toBeCalledWith(
      // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
      testfunction(sampleUserParams, cmpInstance['successCallback'], cmpInstance['errorCallback'])
    );
    // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
    expect(testfunction).toBeCalledWith(sampleUserParams, cmpInstance['successCallback'], cmpInstance['errorCallback']);
  });
});
```

Unit test with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/57847401/index.spec.tsx
  Login
    ✓ handleSubmit (22ms)

-----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File             |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files        |    86.36 |      100 |     62.5 |       85 |                   |
 index.tsx       |       90 |      100 |    71.43 |    88.89 |             27,30 |
 testfunction.ts |       50 |      100 |        0 |       50 |                 2 |
-----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.201s, estimated 4s
```

Here is the completed demo: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57847401

Comment: Really thanks for the help 
So we must create mock file every wants to test action function that been called in component? Thanks

Comment: @RamaN In the demo, I mock the `testFunction` manually in each test file. Are you looking for auto mock? https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#automock-boolean, `automock` is disabled by default.